# How to maintain sidebar placement in Wordpress on WooCommerce pages

Tags: html, wordpress, sidebar, woocommerce

If you use a sidebar in wordpress, you can put things such as a navigation menu in them.

To place the sidebar in the right container element, you simply call `<?php get_sidebar(); ?>` within that element, and the sidebar should be placed inside that.

For example, the following code should result in a sidebar within your wordpress footer:

```
<footer class="footer">
  <div id="inner-footer">
    <div id="main-content-footer" class="span_16">

      <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

This code will work on pages not integrated with WooCommerce, such as a front page.

On pages with WooCommerce, the code generated by `<?php get_sidebar(); ?>` will appear outside the footer in the div element #inner-content, which is within the a parent div called #content.

What files are responsible for placing the sidebar code properly in woocommerce? Is it possible that WooCommerce is generating it's own `<?php get_sidebar(); ?>`? If so, what can I do to make sure my navigation side bar is not affected by WooCommerce?

Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this problem has to do with WooCommerce hooks and how their content is wrapped vs. how "normal" themes are laid out.

The simple fix is to use woocommerce_content() to designate your own template for WooCommerce pages. See documentation here:
http://wcdocs.woothemes.com/codex/third-party-custom-theme-compatibility/

Another way to fix this would be to override their sidebar.php file with your own. Documentation here: http://wcdocs.woothemes.com/codex/template-structure/

Answer (score 0):

Make a copy of the simgle-product.php file in your theme directory (same level as functions.php).  This is the template for the single product pages.  Remove all necessary hooks, including the sidebar hook.  Then, refer to this forum: http://phponlinesupport.com/woocommerce-sidebar-t157932.html to finish the job of making your own custom sidebar for just the shop pages.

Note: When creating the sidebar-shop.php file, be sure to include a

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. This code snipet removes WooCommerce sidebar from appearing after #primary block, so you are able to use get_sidebar('shop') in your layouts.

```
<?php 
// in your themes functions.php

/* remove sidebar */
function woocommerce_remove_sidebar_shop() {
    if( is_woocommerce() )
       remove_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar', 'woocommerce_get_sidebar', 10);
    }

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'woocommerce_remove_sidebar_shop' );

?>
```